# Function reads file and store it in array

Tags: c, arrays, file

I would like to make a function that takes a an array of string and put x number of lines from a file; the lines have a 32 char each, what i did is run through the file first and get the number of line then i made a function that didn't work here is the demo

```
void filArray(char* k,int d,char *tab[]){
char *tab[d];
FILE* fichier = NULL;
int i;
fichier = fopen(k, "r");
if (fichier != NULL)
{for(i=0;i<d;i++)
{

   tab[i]=(char *)malloc((32+1)*sizeof(char));
    fgets(tab[i], d, k);
}
fclose(fichier);
    //printf("\n %d", b);

}}
```

the next one is in my main and it is working but I can't make a function out of it the array is not filled or the type of argument is invalid

```
char line[numberOfchar][BUF];  
plist = fopen(textName, "r");
while(fgets(line[i], 34, plist)) {
line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
    i++;}
total = i;
for(i = 0; i < total; ++i)
    printf("%s\n", line[i]);
```

Comment: `fgets(tab[i], d, k);` --> `fgets(tab[i], 33, k);`

Comment: thx you pointed me out on somthing the K must be a file but stil the tab is have no data

Comment: You are using another variable of the same name (`char *tab[d];`).

Comment: then i need to copy the local tab array into a genaral tabJ that i pass as a parametre ?

Comment: You can use `char *tab[]` directly.

Comment: i just tried the program stops

Comment: Present the whole including the caller.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'.  suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level,  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 3) variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both). 4) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: when posting about a run time problem, as this question is, post a complete, short, cleanly compiles code that still exhibits the problem, post the actual input, post the actual output, post the expected output.

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  multiplying any thing by 1 has no effect.   using that expression in the parameter to `malloc()` just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), the returned value has type `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting the value just clutters the code, making it much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: this line: `fgets(tab[i], d, k);` is saying to input from stdin, at most, `d`-1 bytes.   However, the value of 'd' has nothing to do with the amount of bytes available in each entry in `tab[]`  And `fgets()` will stop before overflowing the input buffer, so as to allow for final NUL byte to be inserted into the buffer.  Suggest: `fgets( tab[i],  33,  k );`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 32+1  Suggest using a `#define` statement or `enum` statement to give those 'magic'  numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code.